# Prove that greatest common divisor of two numbers multiplied with itself divides the product of those numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

$a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}  $
if $c$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, $c^2$ divides $a\cdot b$.

$c = \gcd(a, b) \implies c^2|ab $

How would I prove this? I understand why this sentence is true, but can't formulate it in a mathematically correct way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is very simple.

Since $c=\gcd(a,b)$, so we can write that there exist distinct integers $p,q$ such that $a=cp$ and $b=cq$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Hence $$ab=cp\cdot cq = c^2 \cdot pq$$

Thus we can conclude that $$c^2 | ab$$

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation.

Comment: @CrushedPixel You're welcome.

Comment: You don't need to know $\gcd(p,q)=1$. And $p,q$ don't have to be distinct (e.g. if $a=b$).

Comment: @user236182 well, the only way $p$ and $q$ would not be distinct is if $a=b$, in which case by definition $c=a=b$ so $p=q=1$... but like you said, that doesn't affect the validity of the proof. Of course one could argue it's important to at least _consider_ corner cases like this.

Answer (score 14):

When we say $c \mid a$ we really mean that $\frac ac$ is an integer. Similarily, $c\mid b$ means that $\frac bc$ is an integer. What can you now say about $\frac{ab}{c^2}$? This really has nothing to do with the "$\operatorname{g}$" in the abbreviation "$\gcd$", only the "$\operatorname{cd}$" part is relevant.